# How to make that audio downloads after clicking on button in the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, download

I need to make that it downloads audio under this button :
Download

##### Product Details

Melodic Lil Mosey Type Beat - High,beat is melodic,bouncy and hard,it has the melody and rhythm of a lil Mosey type song,it have prices from range $15-$75,mastered and tagged MP3 licence is $15,un-mastered wav with my tag is $20 and without my tag $25,stems are $40 and Exlusive licence is $75


 



i need to make that it downloads in the same page!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.yourweb.com/audio/file1.mp3" target="_blank">Download</a>
```